# How do you trigger route navigation from javascript in Angular?

Tags: angular, navigation

I've got a simple login component that calls an API to test login with the supplied name and password. On a return of "yuppers, you're logged in", I want to change the page to the home page. The problem is that I don't know how to do so the "Angular way". I have routes and it seems like I'd want to just trigger those so all the Angular magic stays functional, but I could just window.location.href too. I looked up a ton of guides online and there's so many different guides that I can't figure out what the standard or best way is. I have this in my code:

```js
        var response:any = this.Auth.getUserDetails(email, password);
        console.log(response);
        if (response.success)
            $location.path('/home');
```

But vscode is complaining that it doesn't know what $location is. I can add the import manually like so:

```
import {Location, LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';
```

But the docs make it seem like this is a service I should be installing, not an import to use here and there. Am I supposed to create a location service and use the example code on the docs (https://angular.io/api/common/Location)? Do I just import as shown above then set $location = Location or something?

I can't seem to find one guide or video that has all the pieces that make this work.

Comment: this.router.navigate(['/home']); https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: I really suggest you read the documentation, this is very basic angular. This tutorial is helpful to learn the basics of angular: https://angular.io/start

Comment: If the manual was all we needed, we wouldn't need StackOverflow, but thank you regardless. I was able to fill in the missing pieces in the answer you linked and it seems to work now.